# Regex - match all .cs files, but not designer generated files?

Tags: regex

I've got a regex pattern which I am using to match files having particular extensions. However I do NOT want it to match any .Designer.cs files; how would I implement such into my pattern?

`\.(bat|cs|java|html|etc)$`

Comment: It's part of a command I'm sending to CLOC (cloc.sourceforge.net) to count SLOC... so Perl's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a negative look-behind, like this:

```
(?<!\.Designer)\.(bat|cs|java|html|etc)$
```

Comment: Thanks. I used a slight variation so it does not match .Designer.cs but could match .Designer.java, for example: `\.((?<![dD]esigner\.)cs|java|bat)$`

I will accept your answer once the limit is up.

Answer (score 0):

there are some "online regex" - Tester.
I was successful with:

`.*(?<!.designer)(\.bat|\.cs|\.java|\.html|\.etc)$`

(only milliseconds too late ... :-(